# Should I just Shoot My Laptop? Or am I just Retarted?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, window

Alright so I'm probably a dumb a** here but even retards need working computers in this day and age... PLEeeASE HELP!
here's the low down...

-I have a laptop with dual SSDs (both itty bitty)(Asus G74Sx), on this laptop i have (had) an OEM (I think) copy of windows 7.

-The day it was delivered I installed Ubuntu with a dual boot configuration

-Didn't touch windows for close to a year,

-Ubuntu was going great and I needed more space to make it great(er) so I blanked both drives and installed Ubuntu 
(again) on both SSDs (/ on SSD#1 and /home on SSD#2),

-That was awesome, no problem there...

-Than I needed to run several windows only programs off an external HDD and figured I'd give one internal SSD back to Windows 7 and leave one as Ubuntu using my HUGE external HDD as a "go between" storage for both... obviously not an OEM windows this time (Seedy ISO)... but VERIFIED WORKING for over a year on multiple other machines plus MANY other ISOs attempted (all verified to install on multiple other machines).

-During windows 7 install on secondary internal SSD (figgured id just have a dual boot config again) it was taking too long and I tried to cancel install, just locked up on me, so I powered down ***FACE PALM***, this was the original trusted win 7 boot DVD.

-Ever since than my laptop wont recognize linux OR windows DVD/USB 
(all made multiple ways and verified working on multiple other machines) (multiple linux distros / win 7 ISOs on multiple DVDs/USBs burns done with multiple softwares (unetbootin/UUI,WinISO/others(dont remember which))... ALL medias verified working on multiple other machines) (Ive been at this a month now... Ive tried every variation I can think of, If I wasn't already bald I'd be pulling out my hair... as I'm sure you are by my gross over use of parenthesis and dot.dot.dots)

-When I boot override or disable all other boot options (BIOS) this is what it says... "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

-some how during one of the go's I managed to get a copy of mint 15 installed, same disk wouldn't recognize again (fluke?)

-This is my big nice expensive top of the line republic of gamers laptop (vs all my other dated and beaten up loosy goosy laptops) and I'd REALLY like to get this resolved (just thought I'd throw that in there)

-Every OS media I try does the same thing goes straight to grub asking if I want to boot Mint (remember that flukishly installed OKay)

-For the record I AM prioritizing both the DVD and the USB boot options in BIOS and occasionally disabling everything else (SSD)

-USBs are not showing up as hard drives in BIOS (thought I'd throw that out there because I had that issue the other day with a little netbook deal)

Seriously guys I'm at the END OF MY ROPE, I really want to get this machine working again, its the BEST one I have BY FAR, but at the same time I've been at this a month and I'm also growing more and more tempted to pull an office space... I'd really regret that... BUT AAAHHHHHHHH!!!!.... I MEAN SERIOUSLY!!!

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be 2 options; 1) Find a way to correct the Grub settings
or 2) Format both SSD drives and start again.
  There may actually be some info for the 1st option in the ubuntu docmuentation (community, askubuntu). 
  If 2nd option is decided upon, I would recommend an old boot disk from Win98 or WinME on a floppy. This would make it possible to use fdisk /mbr which should clear the master boot record (and therefore clear Grub). The drives should then be accessible. When reinstalling, Do Windows install first. Grub seems to set up better when Windows partition already exists. 
  There is a part of your question that tells of DVD/USB not being accessible.
Double check to see if BIOS 'sees' the optical/usb drives before you start.
There is usually a 'Load BIOS defaults' in saving settings that could correct
normal BIOS 'errors' and return the drives.
  Hope this helps and gets you started to fixing this dilemma. 
Edit 8/11/15 
  Another option would be to format from Win 7 disk. Boot from the Win 7
disk and follow setup to a 'fresh' installation. At the time of choosing
the drive for Win 7, do a fresh install in the drive where 
current Win 7 installation exists. Be sure to format drive. When install
is completed, boot into new installation and go to disk management where
you should be able to format the ubuntu drive, making empty space
for the ubuntu install. Just be certain that ubuntu installs into
that space and should have no problems. Also be sure that / and swap
partitions are created in the ubuntu install.
  Hadn't thought of this at first. Hope this gets you going.  Craig

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the ideal solution would be to blank both drives and start over fresh. Thats actually the ultimate goal. I am having trouble accomplishing this though as it wont boot gparted live dvd /usb. I dont have a floppy drive or disks to try your suggestion. Im tempted to just replace the SSDs with new ones, would this fix the issue or would i just be wasting my money? I think I'll try and drop a HDD from another machine in to see what happens... will post back after, any further advice from anyone smarter than myself out the on the interwebs would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should shoot your laptop and get ASUS G550JX instead. but remember to shoot it with a legal handgun. LOL :P

uhh... actually no. I think you can always start fresh, formatting all your drives and reinstall everything. but remember, there are different installer for Windows OEM, Retail, ....... (forgot the rest, sorry), but you can always modify one of those ISOs. Google is your friend. I reinstalled Windows 8.1 in my ASUS T100 with Windows 8.1 retail DVD and OEM key, after modifying the ei.cfg (if I remember correctly). You should start there. Also before installing, make sure you have all the drivers ready to install. You don't want more headache, do you? You may also want Windows 10, make sure the installer are ready to upgrade as soon as thw Windows 7 installed. Why, you ask? Remember the rules that Windows doesn't give a f**k about another OS in your disk.

After installing Windows, then install Ubuntu. It should auto detect all OSes inside your laptop. You already have experience with that, I think you already know what to do.

Also if the disc still won't boot, try to change your laptop from Legacy BIOS to UEFI, and vice versa. It may help. You didn't specify you got Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit. the 64-bit ones got EFI.

Hope this helps!

(but seriously, why Ubuntu on ROG? you didn't use it for gaming? why not Steam OS?)

Comment: Yes it's 64bit. I'm on efi, and have tried every combo of bios settings possible. I did put in a blank drive and still the same problem. I'm thinking maybe I need to reset my CMOS battery but I can't reach it at the moment (gotta get a longer Philips head).